# How to make border inside triangle?

Tags: html, css

i am making block with arrow and border looks like [image: Desired Result]

And i have tried this.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block-arr {
    background: purple;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.block-arr .inner {
    min-height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.block-arr .inner:after {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid purple;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.block-arr:after {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid purple;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-arr">
    <div class="inner">
        <strong>Main Heading</strong>
        <span>Sub Heading</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i make block like image? And can we make this arrow height responsive?

Comment: CSS is not a graphics language. You can pull off some graphical tricks with hacks, but that isn't what it is designed for. Use SVG if you need graphics.

Comment: Yeah, a triangle in CSS can be done only trough a hack, because it's not really designed for that. Styling hacked elements is even harder because you use pseudo selector and they can only be styled once. You should use SVG.

Comment: @Phiter well i don't agree a lot as we can achieve such thing and even more complex using clever CSS code that we can easily style ... we simply need to think about the right direction. For sure SVG is designed for graphic but CSS can also handle easy graphic

Comment: Yea guys, i have also tried with SVG but back-end developer need code with html css as much as possible because they fill easy to clone/append content in html so i have asked here and @temami understand my situation. Thanks a lot again mate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider a mix of skew transformation, inset box-shadow and some linear-gradient:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-arr {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff)2px 0/2px 100% no-repeat, purple;
  border-left: 2px solid purple;
  z-index: 0;
}

.block-arr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: purple;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px #fff inset;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block-arr:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: purple;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 0px #fff inset;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-arr">
  <strong>Main Heading</strong>
  <span>Sub Heading</span>
</div>
<div class="block-arr">
  <strong>Main Heading</strong><br/>
  <span>Sub Heading</span>
</div>
<div class="block-arr">
</div>
```

And here is a more compressed version with some CSS variable to easily handle color. You can also do the same to handle others variables:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-arr {
  --c1:purple;
  --c2:#fff;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--c2), var(--c2))2px 0/2px 100% no-repeat, var(--c1);
  border-left: 2px solid var(--c1);
  z-index: 0;
}

.block-arr:before,
.block-arr:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--c1);
  border: 5px solid var(--c1);
  border-left: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block-arr:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px var(--c2) inset;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.block-arr:after {
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 0px var(--c2) inset;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-arr">
</div>

<div class="block-arr" style="--c1:red;--c2:yellow">
  <strong>Main Heading</strong>
  <span>Sub Heading</span>
  <p>And yes it is reponsive and grow when height grow</p>
</div>
```

**BONUS**

Another fancy and more complex way with only linear-gradient:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-arr {
  --c1:purple;
  --c2:#fff;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent calc(50% + 4px),var(--c2) calc(50% + 4px),var(--c2) calc(50% + 6px),transparent 0) 100% 100%/50px 50% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent calc(50% + 4px),var(--c2) calc(50% + 4px),var(--c2) calc(50% + 6px),transparent 0) 100% 0/50px 50% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(var(--c2),var(--c2)) 4px calc(100% -  4px)/calc(100% - 58px) 2px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(var(--c2),var(--c2)) 4px 4px/calc(100% - 58px) 2px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(var(--c2),var(--c2)) 4px 4px/2px calc(100% - 8px) no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to top left ,transparent 50%,var(--c1) 50%) 100% 100%/50px 50% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,var(--c1) 50%) 100% 0/50px 50% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(var(--c1),var(--c1)) 0 0/calc(100% - 50px) 100%  no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-arr">
</div>
```

Comment: @Kumar check the update i added another version easier to handle ;)

Comment: That's pretty nice idea mate

Comment: `--c1` will this supported by all browser?? css4??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai it's not CSS4, they are called CSS variable and they are supported by modern browser https://caniuse.com/#search=css-variable .. of course IE is not a modern browser but who care :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the info. First time i am seeing here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, hey mate can u help to fix this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662584/how-can-i-add-an-option-to-show-full-screen-on-owl-slide

for example http://cbip.miranium.com/property/377968/

Answer (score 1):

Using `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements, i have made this design.

Hope it fulfills your requirement.

Thanks

**CSS and HTML:**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
p { margin:0; }
.block-arr {
    background: purple;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.block-arr .inner {
    min-height: 100px;
    /*display: flex;*/
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.block-arr .inner:after {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid purple;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.block-arr:after {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid purple;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.bordered { position:relative; border:1px solid #fff; border-right:none; display: flex; align-items: center; padding:20px; }
.bordered:before, .bordered:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 72%;
    width: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 4;
}
.bordered:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: auto;
    right: -3.3%;
    bottom: -11%;
}
.bordered:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: -12%;
    right: -3.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-arr">
    <div class="inner"><div class="bordered">
        <p><strong>Main Heading</strong>
        <span>Sub Heading</span></p>
        
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you missed the important part :*And can we make this arrow height responsive?* ... and another line of content and see what happen

Comment: Yea, temami is right. You did triangle with border but missed responsive height. Anyway thanks for your help. I really appreciate dude

Comment: Yeah, its not adaptive from height but adaptive from width.